# getting error while complining DeclarationError: Identifier not found or not unique. unit storedData;

Tags: solidity, remix

I am getting the following error while complining DeclarationError:

> Identifier not found or not unique. unit storedData;

```
   pragma solidity ^0.4.0;
//pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0; 
contract SimpleStorage {
    unit storedData;
    
    
    function set(unit x) public {
         storedData = x;
    }
    
    function get() constant public returns (unit) { 
         return storedData;
    }
    
    function increment (unit n) public {
        storedData = storedData + n;
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code has typo in it. In solidity we use `unit` (unsigned integer) not `unit`

here is the working version of your code

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract SimpleStorage {
    uint storedData;
    
    
    function set(uint x) public {
         storedData = x;
    }
    
    function get() constant public returns (uint) { 
         return storedData;
    }
    
    function increment (uint n) public {
        storedData = storedData + n;
        return;
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

unit is not a variable type, use uint256 instead of unit